# Casperjs Testing - deleted QObject

Tags: testing, phantomjs, casperjs, qobject

I'm currently writing some tests with casperjs, and I've run in to an issue while trying to click a button on a webpage.  Here is my code to click the button:

```
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;
this.click(x('//*[@id="xx-xxx"]/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/nav/div[2]/button[5]'));
```

Normally I don't have any issue with button clicks, but for some reason the error being returned is

> Error: cannot call function of deleted qObject

Does anyone know what this means?  What can I do to stop this from happening?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code, please provide a full script. The error suggests that you closed the page. Do you work with frames or popups?

Answer (score 0):

"deleted QObject" usually means that the underlying page object was closed, but you tried to interact with it. This happens for example when clicking something in a popup window which causes the popup to close. When leaving the popup CasperJS tries to do some operation on it, but fails, because the associated memory is already freed.